# use sprintf with char *

Tags: c, serialization, printf, ansi-c

Im trying to use this but when I run it with valgrind I have some memory problems.

For expample

```
char *serialize_file(t_file_package *pack) {

     char *payLoad = malloc(numDigits(pack->file_desc)+numDigits(pack->priority)+strlen(pack->code)+2);
     sprintf(payLoad, "%d#%d#%s", (uint32_t)pack->file_desc,(int16_t)pack->priority, pack->code);
     char *pack = malloc(numDigits(PROCESS) + numDigits((int64_t)strlen(payLoad)) + strlen(payLoad)+2);

     sprintf(pack, "%d#%d#%s",PROCESS, strlen(payLoad), payLoad);
     free(payLoad);
     return pack;
}
```

I know of the existence of asprintf but I downt know why i cant use it in my GNU ANSI C project... My eclipse says that that function is not recognized

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Are you sure that you included stdio.h?

Comment: sprintf is defined in `stdio.h` what error do you have with Valgrind?

Comment: Blood and cacho : Id already include stdio.h and ASPRINTF is not recognized do you know why?

Comment: what about `printf()`? can you try to execute the simplest `Hello World` program to test it?

Comment: @user1544604 because it's not a standard C function, it's a GNU extension. To enable it one needs to define `_GNU_SOURCE` macro before including `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you aren't allowing space for the null character at the end of the string - the string needs space for the digits in "file_desc", the digits in "priority", the characters in "code", the two "#" characters **and** the terminal null character.

The same problem exists with the second call to malloc

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about trailing null character `'\0'`. Add one more byte to argument of `malloc()` calls (replace `+2` with `+3`) and all should be fine.